# i want to update un var inside a url after click on one of button too use outiside the scope in the fetch

Tags: javascript, html, fetch-api

i want to update the url with different value depend with button you click to use after outside in the fetch  primary objectif is to have variable who are update when click that i can use inside the url who change when click on button  and the url i can implement after in other function with the value update

```js
var elementId = "";
var url = ""; // Variable globale pour stocker l'URL

function updateElementId(element) {
  elementId = element.value;

  test();

  return elementId;
}

function test() {
  url = `https://v3.football.api-sports.io/standings?league=${elementId}&season=2023`;
  return url;
}
console.log(url);
console.log(test());

console.log(test());
```

```html
<div>
  <button id="button1" value="5" onclick="updateElementId(this)">
    Bouton 1
  </button>
  <button id="button2" value="45" onclick="updateElementId(this)">
    Bouton 2
  </button>
  <button id="button3" value="3" onclick="updateElementId(this)">
    Bouton 3
  </button>
  <button id="button4" value="75" onclick="updateElementId(this)">
    Bouton 4
  </button>
  <button id="button5" value="42" onclick="updateElementId(this)">
    Bouton 5
  </button>
</div>
```

i want to update the url when click on the button and change the value in var inside the url  to use in the fetch after

Comment: Is there anything wrong with your current code? How is it not working?

Comment: the console.log of url and test() show nothing

Comment: Why not pass the `elementId` to `test` as a parameter instead of relying on unreliable globals?

Comment: You'd need to click one of the buttons in order to set `elementId`. Your `console.log()` lines run immediately though. It's not clear why you think anything would change without calling `updateElementId()`

Comment: tim like that function test(elementId) ?
phil you mean updatelementid(test())

Comment: `console.log(url)` shows the url as blank, because it is before you call `test()` ... the two `console.log(test())` show exactly the same output, because `updateElementId` isn't called anywhere until you click a button, and when you do, nothing is output to the console, because your code doesn't do any `console.log` in `updateElementId` - i.e. your code is doing exactly what you wrote it to do

Comment: that i understand but how i can update when i click

Comment: @zyace you are updating when you click 

Comment: update what exactly? Those `console.log`s don't run when you change something. They run when they run and that's it

Comment: the idea is when i click on one of the button is add the value of the button inside the variable of the url

Comment: what makes you think that doesn't happen? it does. `console.log(url)` after you call `test()`

Comment: you are saying the code work but terminal dont show it

Comment: why would "terminal" show anything if you don't tell it to?

Comment: how do i output after it ?

Comment: how do you output now? console.log ... it works inside functions!!

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly maintain a URL in-memory and alter its query parameters by pressing buttons.

I'd recommend using event delegation to keep the event listeners clean

```js
// for displaying debugging only
const output = document.querySelector("output");

// this is your top-scoped URL
const url = new URL("https://v3.football.api-sports.io/standings?season=2023");

document
  .getElementById("league-buttons")
  .addEventListener("click", ({ target }) => {
    // find the button clicked
    const btn = target.closest("button.league[value]");
    if (btn) {
      // set the URL "league" query parameter
      url.searchParams.set("league", btn.value);

      // This is just for debugging to show you the URL changed
      output.textContent = url.toString();
    }
  });
```

```html
<div id="league-buttons">
  <button id="button1" type="button" class="league" value="5">
    Bouton 1
  </button>
  <button id="button1" type="button" class="league" value="45">
    Bouton 2
  </button>
  <button id="button1" type="button" class="league" value="3">
    Bouton 3
  </button>
  <button id="button1" type="button" class="league" value="75">
    Bouton 4
  </button>
  <button id="button1" type="button" class="league" value="42">
    Bouton 5
  </button>
</div>

<p><output /></p>
```

Then you can use `url` in your `fetch()` calls, triggered however you want

```html
<button id="fetch-data" type="button">Fetch data</button>
```

```js
document.getElementById("fetch-data").addEventListener("click", async () => {
  const res = await fetch(url);
  // ...
});
```

Comment: thank it seem i see the road to the solution

Answer (score -1):

```
const baseUrl = "https://v3.football.api-sports.io/standings";
const output = document.querySelector("output");

function updateAndFetch(leagueValue) {
  const url = `${baseUrl}?league=${leagueValue}&season=2023`;

  fetch(url, {
    method: "GET",
    headers: {
      "x-rapidapi-host": "v3.football.api-sports.io",
      "x-rapidapi-key": ""
    }
  })
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => {
    // Faites quelque chose avec les données, par exemple, afficher dans la console
    console.log(data);
   
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.error("Une erreur s'est produite lors de la récupération des données :", error);
  });
}
```

its working well

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).